# Dynamically configure scope for client registrations with Spring Security 5 OAuth2.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-webclient

I want to dynamically change scope for client registrations.
I know how to set up registrations this way:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          custom:
            client-id: clientId
            client-secret: clientSecret
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
        provider:
          custom:
            token-uri: http://localhost:8081/oauth/token
```

How can I configure this programatically?

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide custom `ClientRegistrationRepository` bean. It is described in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/jc.html#jc-oauth2login-override-boot-autoconfig).

```java
@Configuration
public class OAuth2LoginConfig {

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(this.googleClientRegistration());
    }

    private ClientRegistration googleClientRegistration() {
        return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("google")
            .clientId("google-client-id")
            .clientSecret("google-client-secret")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .redirectUriTemplate("{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}")
            .scope("openid", "profile", "email", "address", "phone")
            .authorizationUri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth")
            .tokenUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")
            .userInfoUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo")
            .userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB)
            .jwkSetUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs")
            .clientName("Google")
            .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like this gets defined at startup. Is there an easy way to make this dynamic? I need the scope to depend on the client request.

Comment: @ThatHansel did you found a solution to make ClientRegistration more dynamic and not during startup?

Answer (score 2):

#### Disclaimer: This is a hacky way, but it works

(and if its stupid but it works, it ain't stupid)

All relevant parts will always use the `ClientRegistrationRepository` to find the ClientRegistration (and with that, the scopes).

So my hacky-way to solve this was to build a wrapper around the `InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository`. In my case, I wanted to allow any additional scope to be requested from the client side, so I wanted to add additional scopes from the query parameter `scope`.

Here's the example code for this solution:

```java
    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository(OAuth2ClientProperties properties) {
        final List<ClientRegistration> registrations = new ArrayList<>(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getClientRegistrations(properties).values());
        // this is the ClientRegistrationRepository that would be used by default configuration
        final ClientRegistrationRepository parent = new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(registrations);

        // this lambda is our wrapper around the configuration based ClientRegistrationRepository
        return (registrationId) -> {
            final ClientRegistration clientRegistration = parent.findByRegistrationId(registrationId);
            if (clientRegistration == null) {
                return null;
            }

            final HttpServletRequest request = Optional.ofNullable(RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
                    .filter(ServletRequestAttributes.class::isInstance)
                    .map(ServletRequestAttributes.class::cast)
                    .map(ServletRequestAttributes::getRequest)
                    .orElse(null);

            final String query;
            if (request == null || (query = request.getQueryString()) == null) {
                return clientRegistration;
            }

            final List<String> scopeQueryParam = parseQuery(query).get(OAuth2ParameterNames.SCOPE);
            if (scopeQueryParam == null) {
                return clientRegistration;
            }

            final Set<String> scopes = scopeQueryParam.stream()
                    .flatMap((v) -> Arrays.stream(v.split(" ")))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

            if (clientRegistration.getScopes().containsAll(scopes)) {
                return clientRegistration;
            }

            final Set<String> resultingScopes = new HashSet<>(scopes);
            resultingScopes.addAll(clientRegistration.getScopes());

            return ClientRegistration.withClientRegistration(clientRegistration)
                    .scope(resultingScopes)
                    .build();
        };
    }

    private static MultiValueMap<String, String> parseQuery(String query) {
        final MultiValueMap<String, String> result = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

        final String[] pairs = query.split("&");
        String[] pair;

        for (String _pair : pairs) {
            pair = _pair.split("=");

            if (pair.length >= 1) {
                final List<String> values = result.computeIfAbsent(URLDecoder.decode(pair[0], StandardCharsets.UTF_8), (k) -> new ArrayList<>());

                if (pair.length >= 2) {
                    values.add(URLDecoder.decode(pair[1], StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```